# AWS - migration failed with error Value of column '' in table '' was truncated to 32768 bytes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I am using the AWS DMS service to migrate my Postgres database to Aurora Postgres but I got in some tables that error

```
Value of column 'ColumnName' in table 'TableName' was truncated to 32768 bytes, actual length: 110644 bytes
```

column type could be `text` or `jsonb`

I can fix it by changing **include LOB option** to be `Full LOB mode` instead of Limited one but that breaks other tables

[image]

any hint on how I can customize that option to these specific tables only

Answer (score 6):

I fixed it by creating a new Database migration task and set **include LOB option**  to `Full LOB mode`